# Adding Tabs to Fragment of navigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

So i know there have been plenty of answered questions about my problem, but i dont know why its not working

The Navigation drawer is working as intenden but im struggling with implementing the tabs. When i created the project i selected the drawer activity at the start if this helps

thx for the help

Sooo, i cleaned up the code and implemented the newer version, for future problems i will post all my code

This ist the Main Activity

```
 package com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import android.view.View;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
        setSupportActionBar( toolbar );
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById( R.id.fab );
        fab.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make( view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG )
                        .setAction( "Action", null ).show();
            }
        } );
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById( R.id.drawer_layout );
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById( R.id.nav_view );
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send )
                .setDrawerLayout( drawer )
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController( this, R.id.nav_host_fragment );
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController( this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration );
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController( navigationView, navController );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.main, menu );
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController( this, R.id.nav_host_fragment );
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp( navController, mAppBarConfiguration )
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

The Layout for Main Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the Fragment where i want to add the tabs (Gallery Fragment)

```
   package com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest.ui.gallery;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TabHost;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTabHost;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;


import com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest.MainActivity;
import com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest.R;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TapAdapter tapAdapter;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        galleryViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of( this ).get( GalleryViewModel.class );
        View root = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false );


        viewPager = (ViewPager) root.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tapAdapter = new TapAdapter( this,getChildFragmentManager() );
        tapAdapter.addFragment(new ShoppingListTab(), "Shopping List");
        tapAdapter.addFragment(new RecipeTab(), "Receipt List");
        viewPager.setAdapter(tapAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);








        return root;
    }



}
```

The Layout File of the Gallery Fragment

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />





        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The Two tab Fragments (RecipeTab and ShoppingListTab)

```
package com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest.ui.gallery;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest.R;

public class RecipeTab extends GalleryFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view1 = inflater.inflate( R.layout.tab_fragment_one, container, false );
        return view1;

    }
}


package com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest.ui.gallery;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest.R;

public class ShoppingListTab extends GalleryFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view1 = inflater.inflate( R.layout.tab_fragment_two, container, false );
        return view1;

    }
}
```

The Layout Files of the two Tabs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

and the tapAdapter

```
package com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest.ui.gallery;



import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TapAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    TapAdapter(GalleryFragment galleryFragment, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

I hope i havent missed anything

Comment: Not Sure, my app keeps crashing when im opening up the gallery fragment, added the exception for this

Comment: realtabcontent, edited the question, i tried to look through the exceptions but i never had one with Looper and Handler

Comment: soshould i just put the layout for the tabs into the gallery layout ?

Comment: i changed the layout but i still get an exception

Comment: i changed the alyout a few times, but i still get the error, i dont really know whats wrong, but i really want to tahnk you for all your help up to this point

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I didn't notice that you'd updated with a new stack trace. You're using the androidx library, judging from that first stack trace, so you want to use `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTabHost>` in your layout, not `<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>`.

Comment: No problem :)
i edited it and get a new exception with the setup which i will google now

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the wrong `setup()`. You have to use one that takes at least a `Context` and a `FragmentManager`; e.g., `mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);`. There's actually a brief example in the docs for the old version: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost. I should also mention that this class has been deprecated, with the current recommendation being to use a `TabLayout` and a `ViewPager` instead. That doesn't mean it won't work; just that they think the new stuff is better. Just FYI.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i try to implement the newer version, the only thing im currently struggling with is setting up the tapAdapter 

tapAdapter = new TapAdapter( this,getSuppotFragmentManager() );
it seems like getSupportFragmentManager wont work in the fragment

Comment: Yeah, `getSupportFragmentManager()` is an `AppCompatActivity` method. To manage `Fragment`s nested inside another `Fragment`, you use the parent `Fragment`'s child `FragmentManager`, which you can obtain with `getChildFragmentManager()`.

Comment: So i changed to a newer version with the ViewPager and i updated all my code and i have a new exception for you

Comment: You're using androidx/material components, which is what the newest versions of the support library are called. Whenever you see something that starts with `android.support`, that's the old versions of the library, so you need to substitute the new classes.  For `TabLayout`, it's `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`, and for `ViewPager`, `androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager`. There's a handy list of substitutions here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings. Also, get rid of the `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTabHost>`, since that's what you're replacing

Comment: ok i think i got it now
i will post the new code and thank you so much for your help, i really dont know how i can thank you for all your work here